# When using Entity Framwork 4.1 for Oracle, long column names create errors

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have two tables that has a column with the same name at the maximum length of 30. 
when I query it in linq with a join of these two tables the actual generated SQL (quite huge by the way) uses the "AS" keyword to differentiate between them, calling them {long_column_name}1 and {long_column_name}2.

when that happens the alias name is actually in the length of 31 which causes to the ORA-00972 error: identifier is too long for the alias name!

this is obviously some kind of a bug in the SQL generation process.

anyone knows of a workaround?
because I can't rename the columns, what I do now is to create two views without these columns, but this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Can you post an example of your linq statement that is generating the problematic query? What I am wondering is if the long column names are in the select, the join clause, etc.

Comment: funny if thats coming from MS.  They should do a substr of the colname || num.

Comment: have u tried Oracle's odp.net w/ entity framework support? I haven't, but see here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html

Comment: @tbone - That's the one I'm using. I believe that they are the one with the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you almost got the solution I was going to suggest.  Instead of creating a view that omits the columns, create a view that has the columns, but use the view to rename those columns to something shorter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up doing it with simplifying the query. It was reasonable for this query, I think that your solution should also work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2344644) is the Oracle Data Provider forum with a matching question. It is confirmed in the link to be an internal bug that they are working on. For now, they say rename the column in the table, which is less than desirable for most scenarios. I would try to map to a view with renamed shorter columns